# How to create a Password field in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

I am making a sign up page and the user have the option to either sign up as a an employee or as an administrator(radio buttons). If he chooses to signup as an administrator i need to add a Password field that he is supposed to know(the company should provide him with that password). 
Here is what i tried

```
<form method="post" action="Registration.php" onSubmit="return valid(this)">
#some code here
Admin<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="v2" value="v2" onclick="ch()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ch(){
    var newInput=document.createElement("input");
    newInput.setAttribute('type','password');
    newInput.setAttribute('name','password');
    newInput.setAttribute('value','password');
    document.getElementById("v2").appendChild(newInput);
    }
</script>
```

NOTE: This is my first time using javascript!
Edited the code,still doesn't work.

Comment: You also need to put it somewhere.

Comment: `.createElement()` will make an element that isn't yet part of your document. You need to use [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to add it to your form.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a new `<input>` element, but you never put it into the document.

If you want to see the element, you need to add it somewhere in the DOM tree by calling `appendChild()` on an existing element.

Comment: @RoudyTarabay: `<input>` elements cannot have children.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is much easier to use:

```
$(selector).append("<input type="password" name="password" value="password">");
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to have a class called "hidden" that hides the element which has that class. so if we click on the employee radio, we give the admin fields' div the hidden class , thus hiding it and remove the hidden class from employee fields.

```
Admin<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="v2" value="v2" onclick="changefields(1)">

Employee<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="v2" value="v2" onclick="changefields(2)">

<div id='employees' class='hidden'>
<!-- input for employees -->
</div>

<div id='admins' class='hidden'>
<!-- input for admins -->
</div>
<script>
function changefields(type){
if(type==2){
$("#employees").removeClass("hidden");$("#admins").addClass("hidden");
}
else{
$("#admins").removeClass("hidden");$("#employees").addClass("hidden");
}
}
</script>

<style>.hidden{display:none}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new element.

```
var newInput=document.createElement("input");
```

and append the same element to DOM by `appendChild()`.